# Fetch Oauth 2.0 token for Authorisation Code Flow

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I can trying to fetch the oauth2 token from token url .I am using authorisation code flow in Oauth2 .
For the token url call ,mandatory parameter is code.
So I need to do a get call on authorization url and get the code.
In postman while doing the authorization call I am getting redirect page(ui to enter credentials)
.Is there any other way to fetch the token using this flow without going through ui as this is specifically testing api
This is for API Automation Testing.

Microsoft documentation attached - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy in OAuth to get a token for a user for automated test scenarios. Authorization Code Flow requires redirects to be followed and complex slow code

Usually you do not want to test Azure AD itself because it is not your code.

One simpler option for automated tests is to use [Resource Owner Password Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20identity%20platform%20supports%20the,by%20directly%20handling%20their%20password.&text=The%20Microsoft%20identity%20platform%20endpoint,AD%20tenants%2C%20not%20personal%20accounts.) to get a token as a user via a simple HTTPS POST. It is not recommended to use this in real UIs though.

Comment: Password Grant is a different flow right .Can we just set this up just for Test Environments,we do not want to have it in prod.And does the developers need to spend some time implementing new flow as well or it can be configured easily.

Comment: There should be zero development work and zero changes to API code. Also no changes at all in prod. The only change would be within automation test clients.